# Order of execution of Multiple Composer Autoloaders

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a project with multiple modules. Each module uses Composer inside itself and is mostly independent of the other modules.

However some modules share dependencies that have different versions. These dependencies are backwards compatible for the most part and use semantic versioning.

I would like to ensure that the dependency with the highest semantic version take precedence. This would allow all modules to share the same dependency and backwards compatibility of these dependencies would ensure nothing breaks.

My plan was to do this by controlling the order in which I call `require_once` on the individual autoloaders. The code below is an example, which in practice is generated.

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/moduleA/vendor/autoload.php');
require_once(__DIR__ . '/moduleB/vendor/autoload.php');
require_once(__DIR__ . '/moduleC/vendor/autoload.php');
```

The main assumption I was making was that if an autoloader is required before another, it would take precedence over later ones.

What I've found though is that the **opposite** is true. The autoloader that comes **last** seems to be taking precedence over the others.

Consider a class `Foo\MyClass` was a dependency shared between these modules. I'm expecting with the above load order, `Foo\MyClass` would be picked up from `moduleA/vendor/...`.

Instead it is coming form `moduleC/vendor/...`.

I could flip my generated order to workaround this, but I'd like to verify if there is a predictable order in which the PHP autoloaders.

Is there an order in which PHP executes Autoloaders? Do multiple Composer autoloaders affect this in any way?

Thanks.

Comment: Found the answer, Composer prepends it's autoloaders by default.

Comment: I have the same situation, today are you using multiple autoloaders or just one with all dependencies?

Comment: I just got the same problem and Composer prepend is so bad! Did you find a solution?

Comment: Found it. Adding "prepend-autoload" config: https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#prepend-autoloader

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, you are in a mess, but you are half way out of this mess already without seeing.

What's bad about your situation is that your modules potentially CAN depend on incompatible third party libraries. You mention they use semantic versioning, but this only covers upwards compatibility, like "minor version increases if a new feature gets added in a compatible way to the older version". Which means that this newer version is not backwards compatible!

Assume module A is using version 1.0.7 of a library, and module B is using version 1.2.5. That library got a new method added to a class in version 1.2, and module B is using that method. Can module B run with the class version 1.0.7 of module A? Of course not. You want both modules to run with the highest compatible version for both modules, 1.2.5.

How to get this? Use only one Composer autoloader and only one central dependency definition.

If you could create a `composer.json` file that contains the dependencies for all the modules A, B and C, and each module states it's dependencies on other libraries, Composer would collect all these libraries, calculate the "best" usable version from it, and create an autoloader that would unambiguously load these libraries only.

Added benefit: Only one version per library without duplicates. Only one autoloader object with global knowledge about all available classes (which could optimize autoloading a bit).

And you are half way there. Each of your modules must already have a local `composer.json` which states the version requirements. Do add a definition for autoloading that module itself, and give it a name. You can then reference that name in the central `composer.json` (you'd probably need to add the repositories if they are private), and you are almost done. Maybe there is some fiddling with paths if you really need these modules in a defined path.

But that's about it.

And then you solve one other thing: What if module A needs some small part of module B? With Composer you can state that dependency together with all the libraries, and even if you forget to install module B, Composer would do it for you, or remind you about it.

Comment: Thanks Sven for the well thought out answer. As you correctly noted this will only cover upwards compatibility. This is unfortunately a stop gap arrangement until the core project adopts Composer. The plan is to eventually move everything over to Composer. But it needs to be done gradually, replacing small pieces. Where each piece is a composer module. Less than ideal, but it's either this or no Composer at all!

Comment: Great answer! I have a similar case, do you know if a autoloader with less vendors has a big impact in performance? I think this would be the only reason to have multiple autoloaders.

Comment: I wouldn't try to estimate any performance numbers without doing the performance tests myself. Which is in fact completely bound to the situation being tested, and is hard to generalize. In other words: Even if you find out that having multiple small autoloaders is a little bit faster for you than a single bigger one, it is only valid for exactly the situation you are measuring. Stating "smaller autoloaders are always faster" is likely wrong, and on top: Managing multiple composer.json dependency files is a real mess and should be avoided.

Comment: A thought on this - if you want to only deploy dependencies for one sub-project, and not include other ones, then this approach isn't ideal. Unless there's an alternative.

Comment: We've run into this with php-jwt. Its in most of the SDKs we have to use for 3rd party APIs... and growing. We absolutely detest composer though and will never put that tripe on our production environment.